# Identity Server Authenticate without password

Tags: security, identityserver4

We have a customer facing API where we give API Keys that map back to users. Once we look up the userName via API Key we then need to get a JWT from identity server. How can this be done without supplying the password?

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a job for a custom grant type. Another option is to issue long lived reference tokens which effectively become the API key.

Comment: something similiar to this? http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/extension_grants.html

Comment: @BradFiresheets exactly that - you can accept anything you like as input and respond with a JWT.